# Parenthesis around "new" in Java Thread trail?

Tags: java, syntax

I'm starting some Java coding in threading and came across a line of code on Oracle's tutorial section I do not understand and I'm hoping someone here can clarify for me why it works:

```
(new Thread(new HelloRunnable())).start();
```

In this line a new thread is declared but not applied directly to an object, and then immediately invokes the start method to run the thread. How does this work? Why does new
 keyword work within this paranthesis? I'd love to have some clarification on what is happening here, thanks. The full source is from:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html

Comment: Thank you for the comments, one specific thing I'd like to know is what syntax purpose is there in having the surrounding parenthesis before new? Is it to instruct the interpreter that we are not applying the new object to a variable?

Comment: The parentheses don't serve any purpose. Remove them and recompile, and the exact same code will be generated.

Comment: Yes. they are just for ease of reading.

Comment: Thanks once again, for clearing things up, I don't like proceeding with doubts in regards to my understanding.

Comment: They don't actually add to the ease of reading at all, *vide* this question. More likely they are there because somebody didn't understand the syntax and thought they were necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The parenthesis around the Thread instance is not necessary. The following will work just as well

```
new Thread(new HelloRunnable()).start();
```

If you expand the statement, it's equivalent to this code

```
Runnable myrunnable = new HelloRunnable();
Thread mythread = new Thread(myrunnable);
mythread.start();
```

The tutorial is being concise.

Answer (score 1):

This line is equivalent to:

```
// I have put it in block, as you don't have a reference to any of those objects afterwards
{
    // instantiate a runnable
    HelloRunnable runnable = new HelloRunnable(); 
    // instantiate a thread object that will use this runnable
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable); 
    // start the thread (call the run method of the runnable on a new thread)
    thread.start(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works because it's a valid statement. It runs the start() method on a Thread object. The Thread object is created as an object, not just declared as a reference variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need an instance of an object that implements `Runnable` to pass to the Thread constructor; the call `new HelloRunnable()` gives that to you.

You need a Thread object to run; the call to `new Thread()` gives that to you.

You call `start()` on that new `Thread` instance; it calls the `run()` method on the `Runnable` instance you gave to its constructor.

Answer (score 0):

1. A new `Thread` object is created and `start` is invoked on it.
2. Why wouldn't it? Creating an object is a separate operation from storing it in a variable. Look at how you create `HelloRunnable`: you're doing the same thing.